# How to make a group object by id with react-native and javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I have this array of objects and I want to regroup each object having the same guid on the same object
For example for this array;

```
  [
      {"guid":"3a03a0a3-ddad-4607-9464-9d139d9989bf","comment":"text"},
      {"guid":"3a03a0a3-ddad-4607-9464-9d139d9989bf","scoreColor":"#fb8537","scoreLabel":"Coaching Later"},
      {"guid":"e400c6df-f6ca-420a-9f69-973d5d572dff","comment":"what"},
      {"guid":"0f608117-4285-4b88-872c-0dd22347b535","comment":"when"},
    ]
```

I want it like that :

```
  [
      {"guid":"3a03a0a3-ddad-4607-9464-9d139d9989bf","comment":"text", 
        "scoreColor":"#fb8537","scoreLabel":"Coaching Later"},

      {"guid":"e400c6df-f6ca-420a-9f69-973d5d572dff","comment":"what"},
      {"guid":"0f608117-4285-4b88-872c-0dd22347b535","comment":"when"},
    ]
```

I try this:

```
const groupBy = (key) => (array) =>
array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return objectsByKeyValue;
  }, {});
const grouped = groupBy('guid');
console.log('results', grouped(data.responses));
```

But it is not the same, that I want...

How can I make it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using object spread syntax and `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const ini = [{
    "guid": "3a03a0a3-ddad-4607-9464-9d139d9989bf",
    "comment": "text"
  },
  {
    "guid": "3a03a0a3-ddad-4607-9464-9d139d9989bf",
    "scoreColor": "#fb8537",
    "scoreLabel": "Coaching Later"
  },
  {
    "guid": "e400c6df-f6ca-420a-9f69-973d5d572dff",
    "comment": "what"
  },
  {
    "guid": "0f608117-4285-4b88-872c-0dd22347b535",
    "comment": "when"
  },
];

const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return Object.values(array.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el[key]] = { ...(acc[el[key]] || {}),
      ...el
    };
    return acc;
  }, {}));
};

console.log(groupBy(ini, 'guid'));
```